# How do I set a timeout for SqlHelper.FillDataset Data Adapter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
private static abc Getabc(string a, int b, int c)
{
    var d = new abc();
    
    try
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("helloworld");
        command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
        SqlHelper.FillDataset(Config.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure,"helloworld", d, new[] {"cat", "dog"},
        new[] {
            new SqlParameter("@bb", b),
            new SqlParameter("@aa", a),
            new SqlParameter("@cc", c),
            });
    }
    
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is the piece of code. Executing this stored procedure is now giving an exception error after 30 seconds which is the default timeout period. The CommandTimeout line doesn't help. Manually executing this Stored Procedure in sql server takes around 1 minute and 15 seconds.

How do I set a timeout period for this piece of code so that it doesn't encounter a timeout exception after 30 seconds?

This usually works but now after a change to one of the table column data type, the SP is taking longer to execute thereby giving an timeout exception while running the code.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; which are you *really* using?

Comment: The SqlHelper looks like it's a new SqlCommand rather than the one you created. Perhaps your SqlHelper has an overload that takes a command object.

Comment: Obligatory comment whenever I see an attempt at wrapping ADO.NET classes: consider throwing away the wheel you've invented yourself in favor of Dapper, as it eliminates most boilerplate without sacrificing performance or flexibility. Very rarely do I see third-party code attempting to do the same and succeeding.

Comment: Set command timeouts for SqlHelper.FillDataset? You can't, [SqlHelper](https://s3.envato.com/files/219470460/html/M-Core.SqlHelper.FillDataset_1.htm) is a static class that doesn't provide any hooks to manipulate the SqlDataAdapter under the covers nor the SqlCommands that it uses. If you need to set the command timeouts you'll need to use something else.